# Prove that $n^2$ is even if and only if $n$ is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, parity

I am practising exam questions and have come across the following.

> Prove that $n^2$ is even if and only if $n$ is even

A contrapositive proof comes to mind, since it must be the case that if $n$ isn't odd then $n$ is even. So $n^2 = (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$ which is odd, hence $n^2$ must be even.

Is this correct?

Comment: This shows that 'if $n$ is odd then $n^2$ is odd', which is the contrapositive of 'if $n^2$ is even then $n$ is even'.  But that is only half of the question, since you're supposed to show an 'if and only if'. So, you still need to show that 'if $n$ is even, then $n^2$ is even'.

Comment: Are you allowed to use "even * even is even" and "odd * odd is odd", or are you meant to prove those?

Comment: I assume that I'm allowed to, but maybe I should state this?

Answer (score 4):

For an if-and-only-if proof, you need to show both ways - you have only done $n$ even $\implies$ $n^2$ even, which is correct. You must show that

- if $n=2k$ for some integer $k$, $n^2=4k^2=2(2k^2)$ is even, which is true
- if $n^2=2t$ for some integer $t$ but $n=2s+1$ is odd for some integer $s$, $$(2s+1)^2=2t\implies 4s^2+4s-2t=2(2s^2+2s-t)=-1$$ is a contradiction as the parities on LHS and RHS are different

Comment: I think you can be clearer: you're answering his question about his own proof, but you're not pointing directly what he's done wrong or hasn't done at all.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Thanks for the reminder! Edited

Comment: +1. Nice answer :)

Comment: Why is the last step necessary?

Comment: You also need to show that is $n^2$ is even, so is $n$. This can be done by assuming that $n^2$ is even and $n$ is odd, reaching a contradiction.

Comment: That's what you're doing here: $n^2 = 2t$ for some integer t but $n = 2s + 1$.

Comment: $( \neg q \Rightarrow \neg p )$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $( p \Rightarrow q ) $. This is what you mean right?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I've already done the right side, so:
$ L = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$.

Now I must just figure out the left side.

Comment: $2t=(2s+1)^2→(2s+1)^2-2t=0→4k^2+4k+1-2t=0→4k^2+4k-2t=-1→2(2k^2+2k-t)=-1$.

So the trick is, in a way, to factor out the 2, since any integer times two is trivially even, by the definition of an even number is even and an odd number is odd.

Comment: Correct. That's what I have in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've proved that if $n^2$ is even then so is $n$. So you've proved the "only if" direction, but not the "if".

So you've just got to show that the square $n^2$ of an even number $n=2k$ is even, and you've got the "if" as well. Put them together and you're there.

Comment: $( \neg q \Rightarrow \neg p )$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $( p \Rightarrow q ) $. This is what you mean right?

Comment: @Travitrinket Yes, that exactly :-)

Answer (score -1):

$n>1;$

$D_n:= n^2-n=n(n-1); $

$D_n$ is even, since either $n$ or $(n-1)$ is even.

1) $n$ is even $\Rightarrow$

$n^2 = D_n +n$ is even;

(Sum of $2$ even numbers)

2)$n^2$ is even $\Rightarrow$

$n= n^2-D_n$ is even;

(Difference of $2$ even numbers)

Used: Sum and difference of $2$ even numbers is even(Why?)

Comment: Quote: "This is a proof-verification question. You did not answer him."